# Blender 3D - Rolling a ball on a predrawn path on a flat surface without slipping and also following physic(rolling)

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, rigid-body-simulation

I want to create a realistic simulation of a rolling ball on a plane, following a custom path that I draw. The ball has three internal axes (x, y, and z) initially aligned with the world's origin axis (x for right, y for front, z for up). As the ball moves and rolls, these internal axes also rotate and change their position accordingly.

The path I have designed includes straight lines, complex movements, sudden stops, and 90-degree turns where the ball rolls instantly to the right or left without changing its facing direction.

I have attempted several methods, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to make the ball move as intended. The most promising approach I tried(by then looked like it) was aligning two planes on top of each other, with the ball sandwiched between them. The lower plane is passive, while the upper plane is active and follows a path constraint(all three have rigit body physic property and correct shapes(mesh and sphere)). The target path is a Bezier curve that I created and edited to match the desired ball movement. However, when I played the animation, the plane followed the path correctly, but the ball either moved randomly without making sense of the path or doesnt move at all.

I experimented by slightly moving the upper plane downward (so it overlaps with the ball's top surface) and also applied a solidify modifier to the upper plane, but neither of these approaches yielded the desired results.

At this point, I in need help/guidance. I tried many ideas, and the only remaining possibility that I can think of working as of right now is to explore the potential of utilizing armature/skeleton, but I'm yet to learn that and experiment to see if possible at all.

Comment: i quite don't understand why you want to use rigid body, if you want to animate the ball on a curve? Rigid body means: real world physics, it means exactly the opposite: not being animated. So i think you used the wrong way here. Do i understand you right, that you just want that the ball rotates in correct speed on the ground as you are animating it on the curve? That's all you want?